# Why iPad is not listed in the Personal Hotspot area as the iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, tethering

I'm using internet from iPad/iPhone sometimes. The image bellow shows both devices but I don't understand why they are listed in different fields.

Why iPad is not listed in the Personal Hotspot area as the iPhone?

[image]

I see all devices from icloud.com. This means they are in the same account?

[image]

Comment: Are you signed in to the same Apple ID on both the iPhone and the iPad?

Comment: How can I check this? I was always thinking all devices are on the same ID. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Having the same problem. All accounts with the same appleid, same wifi... both iPad and iPhone with SIM card in it.

Answer (score 1):

The Personal Hotspot is for devices signed in using the same Apple ID. Even if your hotspot is turned off it will still show up if you have the same Apple ID.

The lower portion is any detectable networks, including hotspots.

Comment: Question update with indication that all devices are in the same ID. Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Does your iPad have a cellular data plan? It won't create a hotspot if it can't provide data to a connected device.

Comment: Yes there is a data plan on iPad.